# Reshaping wide to long with multiple varying variables and unbalaned time

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have two varying groups of variables: annualpercentage and year. annualpercentage starts from 1999 and ends at 2012, but year starts from 1999 until 2013.

```
countrylabel annualpercentageshare.1999 year1990 year1991 year1992
1      Austria                         NA       NA       NA       NA
2      Belgium                         NA       NA       NA       NA
3     Bulgaria                   48.20000       NA       NA       NA
4      Estonia                         NA       NA       NA       NA
5       France                   47.52853       NA       NA       NA
6      Germany                         NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Something like this.

I already tried this code:

```
merge_data2 <- reshape(merge_data2, varying = list(2:ncol(merge_data2)), 
                       v.names = c("percentageshare", "Year"),
                       idvar = "countrylabel", direction = "long", times = 1990:2013)
```

but I got this error message:

> "Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
>     'lengths(varying)' must all match 'length(times)'"

EDIT: I want a dataframe like this:

```
countrylabel    time      annualpercentageshare        year
Austria          1990            NA                      NA
Austria          1991            NA                      NA
```

Comment: It's pretty much just `reshape2::melt(merge_data2, id = "countrylabel")`. If you need to fill in the missing years, that's a second step.

Comment: Alternatively, with `dplyr`: `gather(merge_data2, -countrylabel, key = metric, value = Value)`

Comment: @Mako212: it doesn't work. It gives me three variables: countrylabel, variable, and value, with `variable' containing only "annualpercentageshare.1999" up til "annualpercentageshare.2012"

Comment: @Rainroad it should also contain rows for all the "year" columns.

Comment: @Mako212: Sorry I guess I wasn't being clear enough in my question. I just edited my question to display the dataframe format I want.

Comment: @Jordo82: I tried but it also gave me similar results to Mako212's

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -countrylabel) %>%
  separate("variable", into = c("stat", "time"), sep = -4) %>%
  spread(stat, value)
```

output

```
   countrylabel time annualpercentageshare. year
1       Austria 1990                     NA   NA
2       Austria 1991                     NA   NA
3       Austria 1992                     NA   NA
4       Austria 1999                     NA   NA
5       Belgium 1990                     NA   NA
6       Belgium 1991                     NA   NA
7       Belgium 1992                     NA   NA
8       Belgium 1999                     NA   NA
9      Bulgaria 1990                     NA   NA
10     Bulgaria 1991                     NA   NA
11     Bulgaria 1992                     NA   NA
12     Bulgaria 1999               48.20000   NA
13      Estonia 1990                     NA   NA
14      Estonia 1991                     NA   NA
15      Estonia 1992                     NA   NA
16      Estonia 1999                     NA   NA
17       France 1990                     NA   NA
18       France 1991                     NA   NA
19       France 1992                     NA   NA
20       France 1999               47.52853   NA
21      Germany 1990                     NA   NA
22      Germany 1991                     NA   NA
23      Germany 1992                     NA   NA
24      Germany 1999                     NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`reshape` likes `"."`, so firstly we insert one into the `year*` variables.

```
names(d) <- gsub("year", "year.", names(d))
```

Now after we have given `reshape` the missing columns and `order`,

```
d$annualpercentage.2002 <- NA
d$year.1999 <- NA
d <- d[c(1, order(names(d)[-1]) + 1)]
```

your idea works by defining the different column sorts in `varying` in a list:

```
res <- reshape(d, varying=list(2:5, 6:9), direction="long", idvar="countrylabel", 
               times=1999:2002, v.names=c("annualpercentage", "year"))
res
#                  countrylabel time annualpercentage        year
# Austria.1999          Austria 1999               NA          NA
# Belgium.1999          Belgium 1999               NA          NA
# Bulgaria.1999        Bulgaria 1999       -0.6806495          NA
# Estonia.1999          Estonia 1999               NA          NA
# France.1999            France 1999               NA          NA
# Germany.1999          Germany 1999               NA          NA
# Switzerland.1999  Switzerland 1999       -1.8497570          NA
# Austria.2000          Austria 2000       -0.6033900  0.14970015
# Belgium.2000          Belgium 2000               NA -0.49201756
# Bulgaria.2000        Bulgaria 2000        0.8263925 -0.36320990
# Estonia.2000          Estonia 2000               NA -2.51032544
# France.2000            France 2000               NA  0.57800624
# Germany.2000          Germany 2000               NA -0.52295712
# Switzerland.2000  Switzerland 2000        0.2783076  0.25616728
# Austria.2001          Austria 2001       -2.6962484 -0.15375642
# Belgium.2001          Belgium 2001        1.3088577  0.72528621
# Bulgaria.2001        Bulgaria 2001               NA          NA
# Estonia.2001          Estonia 2001               NA -0.05563662
# France.2001            France 2001        0.2224629  0.74205086
# Germany.2001          Germany 2001               NA -0.01185349
# Switzerland.2001  Switzerland 2001        0.8354322 -1.40826638
# Austria.2002          Austria 2002               NA          NA
# Belgium.2002          Belgium 2002               NA  1.60874778
# Bulgaria.2002        Bulgaria 2002               NA          NA
# Estonia.2002          Estonia 2002               NA  0.55866704
# France.2002            France 2002               NA -1.59866472
# Germany.2002          Germany 2002               NA -0.11217415
# Switzerland.2002  Switzerland 2002               NA          NA
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(countrylabel = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", 
"Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Switzerland"), annualpercentage.1999 = c(NA, 
-2.58060150400384, -0.0623757258909573, 0.267776001395166, NA, 
NA, 0.048219924249952), annualpercentage.2000 = c(NA, -0.249416955035044, 
1.3525450891501, 1.04446768824697, NA, -0.0582347596434839, -0.891400228849837
), annualpercentage.2001 = c(1.82469277697851, NA, NA, 1.04231605324821, 
NA, -0.900145118946308, -1.19320727433597), year2000 = c(0.633712375393134, 
NA, 1.24760861316098, -0.092964787061478, -0.59403260962332, 
NA, -0.650348234181285), year2001 = c(0.587318286831079, NA, 
NA, 0.348890470222513, NA, NA, NA), year2002 = c(0.0645316087966406, 
-0.279456557428068, NA, NA, -0.0627400036074545, 1.30419117694731, 
-0.484654596062051)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is the 'varying=list(m:n, z:y)' part needed for getting the reshaping correctly when having multiple varying variables?

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the original reshape code, the error lies in using `list(2:ncol(d))`, which only creates a list of the numbers of the columns:

```
list(2:ncol(d))
```

What you need is the vector with the names of the columns:

```
list(colnames(d)[2:ncol(d)])
```

Therefore,

```
merge_data2 <- reshape(merge_data2, varying = list(colnames(merge_data2)[2:ncol(merge_data2)]), 
                       v.names = c("percentageshare", "Year"),
                       idvar = "countrylabel", direction = "long", times = 1990:2013)
```

will render what you are after.